IPC_LOCK not available at LXC startup during boot
I am running a Linux Container (LXC) with (Hashicorp) vault installed that requires IPC_LOCK.
Whenever I reboot or boot, it fails to start up vault with autostart. From what I can see in the logs it complains on a lack of IPC_LOCK.
However, this is not an issue when I manually restart it.
I have added different delays to try and remedy this, but it seems not to work.
I want to ask if there is a systemd target or service that checks if such kernel capabilities are available before starting the LXC service, but maybe I am missing something more fundamental here?

How do you "manually restart" it – via systemd, or via shell directly?

@u1686_grawity I restart the lxc container through the shell directly. But from what I can read the lxc service is a system service and should run as root, no?

captree can help you see what capabilities are available to services. Some distributions provide this tool by default.
